# How much of the Java 6 API is implemented by Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to port an small open source AES encryption class to Android, and it would cut my work down a lot if the API of Android is as close as possible to the Java 6 API.

How much is implemented (or referenceable), as I have tried searching about this on google, and i have not yet come up with anything useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO In general Java 6 works. The compiler does the work for you.

Re self implementing encryption: Please try using [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/). In general, self implementation of any known crypto algorithm isn't a good idea.

Comment: thanks for this. the bouncy castle implementation seems a bit overkill for what i'm trying to do. i am just planning to get my feet wet with android, by making a small file encryption app. not really sure how complex it will get, as my background is in web apps, not single-focus apps, and i haven't really done much java.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked the Java library reference on http://developer.android.com/reference/ ?

Comment: The Android API isn't the same as Java API!

Comment: As Android is Java-based and it also uses Java's compiler, you can answer the question yourself. Try out your Java 6 code.

Comment: tuergeist: I thought the compiler was completely different since Android has its own byte code and interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

The compile progress of android project is like that, first compile the source code with java compiler(mainly on SE 5.0 API ) into java byte code as .class file, and such class files will be compiled continuously by dalvik VM into dalvik byte code .dex file. When the app runs, it is in fact .dex running on dalvik vm.

Answer (score 1):

In general you shouldn't have a lot of problem as long as you're not using any graphics or sound-related libraries. Android does not support swing or awt.

Also, this isn't an android limitation, but you'll probably going to be having a lot of trouble with floats, since the platforms that android usually runs on (ARM) do not have a Floating point unit, so you might need to take that into consideration

Comment: I assume they can still DO floating point operations, they'll just be much slower than you're used to?

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum some of the new functions in java.utils.Arrays are missing.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10054

Answer (score 0):

The new language-side features of Java 6 (such as @Override annotation for interfaces) will generally work; Dalvik VM compiler is compatible with Java 6 *.class files.
On the other hand, the new API features of JDK6, such as String.isEmpty(), java.util.Arrays.copyOf, etc, are either missing or need newer API levels. (API 9 or later in these examples)
If your application targets old Android devices (API 8 or lower), you can only use Java 5 functions.