# Why aren't Java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit types greater than SECONDS available in Android?

Tags: java, android, java.util.concurrent

I miss `MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS`, which exist in [documentaion](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) since API level 1 (I use 7th or 2.1 version for the application).

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472423/android-java-util-concurrent-timeunit-convert-milliseconds-to-minutes), where this miss was also pointed out (though, it wasn't in the question itself), but as solution making own calculations was only proposed.

I am not lazy, but I send some data to server (Java project), where `TimeUnit.MINUTES` or `TimeUnit.HOURS` are actively used. Just want to avoid mistakes.

Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: So what's the question? It looks like you understand that some TimeUnit constants are not available on android. Only platform developers know why they did so.

Comment: "Write to Android developers and ask" is also an answer:). And first I was trying to understand, whether that is known/solved or my-developer-environment-specific or whatever else problem. Who knows, maybe platform Developers also use Stackoverflow?

Comment: they do, but still it's better to ask the directly ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open the javadoc for `TimeUnit` on [java 5](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) and [java 6](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) side by side you will see that these were added in java 6. Android so far only implements java 5.

Comment: Well, that explains the absence a bit. But still there exists some inconsistency in Android documentaion for TimeUnit then. And I have not found any clue for Java version being used in Android, [some say Java 6 also works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091114/how-much-of-the-java-6-api-is-implemented-by-android).