# Override androids implementation of TimeUnit

Tags: android

As [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472423/android-java-util-concurrent-timeunit-convert-milliseconds-to-minutes) 2 [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497324/why-arent-java-util-concurrent-timeunit-types-greater-than-seconds-available-in) clearly show, the android implementation of the jdk do not include some of the `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` enum values, particularly `DAYS`.

Since I am extensively using a common library which references `TimeUnit.DAYS` I need the enum value to exist. I know the functionality of `TimeUnit.DAYS` is the same as `TimeUnit.HOURS * 24` however I can't change the implementation of the referenced library.

How would I go about overriding the android jdk implementation of this Enum so that I stop getting the `NoSuchFieldError` at runtime?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not likely to find a solution.  Even if you could override the built in TimeUnits class (I don't believe you can) you would have no way to feed the new one into your library and get it to work.

In normal java you could replace the classloader before loading the library but that would be a really bad (and difficult) solution anyway.

If your library is open-source or if you own it, I'd recommend fixing it and rebuilding--seems pretty straight-forward.  If you submit a patch and tell them why then it should automatically be included in future versions.

If you don't own it, you have to get the person or group who does to rebuild it (This is the reason old-school programmers hate closed source, even if you are willing to do it yourself, you are often completely blocked).